# fastlane build problems - doubled pathname

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fastlane

Just started using fastlane (v2.118.1) and immediately ran into build problems.

Here is the lane from my Fastfile:

```
lane :beta do
  build_app(workspace: "projectname.xcworkspace", scheme: "schemename")
end
```

Here is the redacted Appfile:

```
app_identifier("redacted")
apple_id("redacted")    
itc_team_id("redacted")
team_id("redacted")
```

Redacted values are valid. Build runs and build is produced, but the following errors show:

```
INFO [2019-03-25 10:56:28.23]: ------------------------------
INFO [2019-03-25 10:56:28.23]: --- Step: default_platform ---
INFO [2019-03-25 10:56:28.23]: ------------------------------
INFO [2019-03-25 10:56:28.23]: Driving the lane 'ios beta' 
INFO [2019-03-25 10:56:28.23]: -----------------------
INFO [2019-03-25 10:56:28.23]: --- Step: build_app ---
INFO [2019-03-25 10:56:28.23]: -----------------------
INFO [2019-03-25 10:56:28.28]: $ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace projectname.xcworkspace -scheme schemename
DEBUG [2019-03-25 10:56:29.63]: Parsing project file '/Users/username/Documents/somefolder/Users/username/Documents/somefolder/projectname.xcodeproj' to find selected provisioning profiles
DEBUG [2019-03-25 10:56:29.63]: Finding provision profiles for 'Release'
ERROR [2019-03-25 10:56:29.63]: Couldn't automatically detect the provisioning profile mapping
ERROR [2019-03-25 10:56:29.63]: Since Xcode 9 you need to provide an explicit mapping of what
ERROR [2019-03-25 10:56:29.63]: provisioning profile to use for each target of your app
ERROR [2019-03-25 10:56:29.63]: [Xcodeproj] Unable to open '/Users/username/Documents/somefolder/Users/username/Documents/somefolder/projectname.xcodeproj' because it doesn't exist.
```

NOTE: the pathname contains the path to the xcodeproj file twice: '/Users/username/Documents/somefolder/Users/username/Documents/somefolder/projectname.xcodeproj'

There is no error when building and archiving with Xcode IDE, and I can submit my build to TestFlight with no error. This problem only occurs in fastlane.

How can I diagnose where that path is getting doubled?

Comment: Best use https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/new?template=BUG_REPORT.md and fill the template - we can help you there much better. (First step: Add `--verbose` to the command you are running for maybe more output)

Comment: @janpio Output is already verbose. I don't yet know if this is a bug. Could be something I've done.

Comment: Possible, but simpler to debug/chat about in https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/14472

Comment: I did post an issue https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/14472

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted [here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/14472), the issue was that somehow the xcworkspace contents had become corrupted and had the raw path to the xcodeproj file included and marked as relative to group. I was able to resolve it by editing xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata using TextEdit to correct the path.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Hint for others: When using CocoaPods you can delete the `.xcworkspace` file and run `pod install` again. This recreates the `.xcworkspace`.